# The Ruby Racer, RuntimeError - SyntaxError: unexpected indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, therubyracer

After an upgrade of ruby and rails performed on an old app, I get the following error when trying to access to any of the app views:

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:3:1: unexpected indentation
```

It seems that some file related to The Ruby Racer gem may be causing this issue.

Ruby 2.3.1p112, Rails 4.0.13, therubyracer 0.12.3

In the server log:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError - SyntaxError: [stdin]:3:1: unexpected indentation:
  execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:98:in `wrap_error'
  execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in call'
  execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:44:in `block in call'
  execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
  execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
  execjs (2.7.0) lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
  coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in `compile'
```

**Update**

Using a previous version of therubyracer such as `gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.2'` does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a compilation error during the compilation of one of your coffee scripts. You should check the `coffee` files inside your `assets/javascript` folder.

To help you debug more easily where the problem is (which line), you can try to install coffee-script manually (http://coffeescript.org) and use the command line compiler.

Comment: No changes were made on coffee script files during the upgrade. I double-checked these few and short files, but there are no indentation issues.

Comment: Even if you have made no changes to your files, there's still a coffee script compilation error. So one way to find out where is the problem is to do by dichotomy. Just remove all the coffee script files of your project and reimport them one by one until you find out where the problem is.

Comment: Checked one of the files with the compilator. The problem was this file:


`jQuery ->
  $('#subscription_product_tokens').tokenInput '/en/search_products.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#subscription_product_tokens').data('load')
    propertyToSearch: "full_description"`

Quite odd. I rewrote it to:


`jQuery ->
  $('#subscription_product_tokens').tokenInput '/en/search_products.json'
  theme: 'facebook'
  prePopulate: $('#subscription_product_tokens').data('load')
  propertyToSearch: "full_description"` (Only two spaces of indentantion before "theme" line.